# Promises: Image loading timing issue

Tags: javascript, promise, timing

I am trying to preload an image with JavaScript and fade it in once loaded.

I also want to learn something about Promises, I am using this [tutorial JS code](https://github.com/mpj/fpjs8/blob/master/src/load-image.js) to load the image:

```
function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function () {
            resolve(image);
        };

        image.onerror = function () {
            var message = 'Could not load image at ' + url;
            reject(new Error(msg));
        };

        image.src = url;
    });
}
```

(I corrected a small bug regarding a wrong variable name and pushed it to babel to make it ES5 conform despite the Promise)

I use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageEl = $('.myImg');

    loadImage(imageEl.data('src')).then(function(image) {
        imageEl.attr('src', image.src);
        imageEl.addClass('myImgLoaded');
    });
});
```

With this CSS:

```
.myImg {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s;
}

.myImgLoaded {
    opacity: 1
}
```

And minimal HTML:

```
<img data-src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any" class="myImg">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btL7vjbh/)

It kind of works, but there seems to be a timing problem somewhere. To see it for yourself, maybe try the Fiddle and throttle the connection with devtool. Then you will see that often the `myImgLoaded` is added before the image appears. When it appears, the transition is already over and it builds up really ugly.

But I can't figure out where the problem is. When `.then()` is called the image is already preloaded so `imageEl.attr('src', image.src)` should be instant, or am I wrong? Why there is this timing problem?

Comment: If the image is already loaded (for example, it was cached) the above won't work, you need to check if the image is loaded and resolve in time.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You mean using the image's `complete` property? But how can this be, I always create a `new image`?

Comment: It might be a way to keep the image in a hidden class, `display: none;` and once loaded to toggle the class to fade in by CSS animation.